# What data structure should be returned as the final entity when the question asks for returning a tree

Tags: data-structures, tree

So, I am working on a LeetCode problem to construct a tree from the given In-order and Pre-order tree traversal sequences. The given skeletal code is as follows:

```
# Definition for a binary tree node.
# class TreeNode:
#     def __init__(self, val=0, left=None, right=None):
#         self.val = val
#         self.left = left
#         self.right = right
class Solution:
    def buildTree(self, preorder: List[int], inorder: List[int]) -> TreeNode:
```

From what I understand, are we expected to return the root node after constructing the tree?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, we would return the root for trees (and head for LinkedList-type questions):

```
class Solution:
    def buildTree(self, preorder, inorder):
        if inorder:
            index = inorder.index(preorder.pop(0))
            root = TreeNode(inorder[index])
            root.left = self.buildTree(preorder, inorder[:index])
            root.right = self.buildTree(preorder, inorder[index + 1:])
            return root
```

---

Here is an official solution of LeetCode with comments:

```
class Solution:
    def buildTree(self, preorder, inorder):
        """
        :type preorder: List[int]
        :type inorder: List[int]
        :rtype: TreeNode
        """
        def helper(in_left = 0, in_right = len(inorder)):
            nonlocal pre_idx
            # if there is no elements to construct subtrees
            if in_left == in_right:
                return None
            
            # pick up pre_idx element as a root
            root_val = preorder[pre_idx]
            root = TreeNode(root_val)

            # root splits inorder list
            # into left and right subtrees
            index = idx_map[root_val]

            # recursion 
            pre_idx += 1
            # build left subtree
            root.left = helper(in_left, index)
            # build right subtree
            root.right = helper(index + 1, in_right)
            return root
        
        # start from first preorder element
        pre_idx = 0
        # build a hashmap value -> its index
        idx_map = {val:idx for idx, val in enumerate(inorder)} 
        return helper()
```